# React styled-components: How to Style Implicitly Rendered Components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am using `styled-components` to implement a light/dark theme into my application. Not sure if it matters too much, but I am using TypeScript. I am still pretty new to React and TS.

This is straightforward when the component is a basic HTML element:

```js
export const StyledEllipsis = styled.div`
  &:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px ${props => props.theme.shadow};
  }
`
```

Or on a custom component (I may or may not own the type). Here I am styling the `ResponsiveGridLayout` from `react-grid-layout`:

```js
export const StyledReactGridLayout = styled(ResponsiveGridLayout)`
  background-color: ${props => props.theme.tertiary};
`
```

However I get tripped up when I need to styled components that I do not explicitly render. For the examples above, somewhere in code I obviously have:

```html
...
  <StyledReactGridLayout> ... </StyledReactGridLayout>
...
```

But what about styling say the children of `<StyledReactGridLayout/>` that I don't render myself? In the DOM I can see other child components that `react-grid-layout` renders, such as `<ReactGridItem/>`. What if I want to change the theme on this component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply get the child components class names via the browser inspector and style them like this:

```js
export const StyledReactGridLayout = styled(ResponsiveGridLayout)`
  background-color: ${props => props.theme.tertiary};

  .react-grid-item {
    background-color: // whatever color u want (u can use props here too);
  }
`
```

Nesting works in styled-components like sass.